# How do I select a part of an array? Or match parts of one array with parts of another?

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, flash-cs5

I have some drag and drop function where there are 8 items (dragArray) that can be dropped onto 2 big 'landing zones' (matchArray). But since I don't want them lie on top of each other, I've made an array where they are given positions (posArray).

```
var dragArray:Array = [drag_1, drag_2, drag_3, drag_4, drag_5, drag_6, drag_7, drag_8];
var matchArray:Array = [drop_1, drop_1, drop_1, drop_1, drop_2, drop_2, drop_2, drop_2];
var posArray:Array = [{x:412,y:246},{x:530,y:218},{x:431,y:186},{x:470,y:152},{x:140,y:111},{x:108,y:162},{x:179,y:210},{x:113,y:254}];
```

When all 8 items are dropped, a check button appears and I want to check if they are dropped onto the correct big landing zone. I tried using the following:

```
if (posArray[i].x != dragArray[i].x || dragArray[i].y != posArray[i].y )
```

But then, not only the landing zone must match, but the positions must also match.

When I use

```
if (matchArray[i].x != dragArray[i].x || dragArray[i].y != matchArray[i].y )
```

it doesn't work, because the positions of the (dragArray) items don't match with the registration points of the (matchArray) landing zones.

Is there any way of checking if the first 4 (drag_1, drag_2, drag_3, drag_4) items match with ANY of the first 4 posArray positions and the last 4 (drag_5, drag_6, drag_7, drag_8) match with ANY of the last 4 posArray positions?

Comment: I don't know if I entirely understand the question but it sounds like you need a nested loop, instead of using i to step through both sets simultaneously you may need to step through one array for each element of another array (possibly using a boolean to keep track of if some condition has occurred as you step through the inner loop).

Comment: I'm not a real actionscript hero, so I'm not sure if I understand you either, but it sounds reasonable.
By nested you mean something like
    `if ((posArray(0) || posArray(1) || posArray(2) || posArray(3)).x != dragArray[i].x || dragArray[i].y != (posArray(0) || posArray(1) || posArray(2) || posArray(3)).y )`
But then probably written completely else, but with this idea.
Or am I missing the point now?

Comment: Tried this 
`if (((posArray[0] || posArray[1] || posArray[2] || posArray[3]).x != (drag_1 || drag_2 || drag_1 || drag_4).x || (drag_1 || drag_2 || drag_1 || drag_4).y != (posArray[0] || posArray[1] || posArray[2] || posArray[3]).y) || ((posArray[5] || posArray[6] || posArray[7] || posArray[8]).x != (drag_5 || drag_6 || drag_7 || drag_8).x || (drag_5 || drag_6 || drag_7 || drag_8).y != (posArray[5] || posArray[6] || posArray[7] || posArray[8]).y))`
but no luck. Guess I'm missing the point...

Comment: I'll explain in an answer, not enough room in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to check each element of one set against all elements of another set then you'll need to have two loops, one "nested" within the other.  The general form of this algorithm in AS3 looks like

```
var allMatched:Boolean = true;

for(var i:Number=0; i<array1.length; i++)
{
    var matchFound:Boolean = false;
    for(var j:Number=0; j<array2.length; j++)
    {
        if(array1[i]==array2[j])
        {
            matchFound=true;
            break; //exit the inner loop we found a match
        }
    }
    if(!matchFound)
    {
        allMatched=false;
        break; //we found an element in one set not present in the other, we can stop searching
    }
}
if(allMatched)
     trace("Everything from array1 was found somewhere in array2");  //For an element a in the set A there exists an element b in set B such that a = b
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks. It looks ok. But I'm having a hard time tailoring it to my specific case.
I guess your suggested code should replace my `if (posArray[i].x != ...)`, and I should use the `if(allMatched)` to perform the actions I wanted to perform with my if-code. And I suppose that your "array1" should be my "dragArray" and your "array2" should be my "posArray". Am I correct?
Do you think it would work if I make 2 loops, one for `i<4;` and one for `3<i<8;` instead of `i<array1.length;`, so I can match the first half of my dragArray with the first half of the posArray and the second halves the same?

Comment: No problem, yeah you can assume array1 array2 would be replaced by the arrays you want to check.  In terms of the ranges you could like you say either split them into two loops or you could take a look at the methods provided by Array in the docs, most likely some of those methods would help you appropriately split things up before comparing (be wary of what you do with those methods some modify the original array some return a new one).  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html

Comment: I'll give it a shot tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: I've tried it. But i get stuck at getting a match. I used the `if(array1[i]==array2[j])` (adopted it to my code ofc). But it seems to have a problem with what's in it. Because one of both seems to output x and y coordinates and the other just index numbers. For deadline reasons I'll make my project on another (uglier) way now. But I would love to have it fully working for new projects.

Comment: By the way, I used the slice method (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#slice()) to break my arrays in pieces. `var halfDrag1:Array = dragArray.slice(0,4);` (and so forth)